# How do I prepare a PDB for submission to the Protein Data Bank?

Tags: bioinformatics, structural-biology, ccp4, pdb

I have a couple structures that are nearly ready to be deposited in the PDB.  Out of curiosity, I ran them through the ADIT's precheck tool and they failed with one error after another, as I lacked all sorts of additional records (`TER`, `SEQRES`, `HETNAM`, etc.) that my refinement and modelling tools don't seem to care about.

From what I understand/guess, the online submission tool will help fill in all the metadata (`REMARK`s, etc.), but how do I turn my coordinates into something acceptable?

Comment: Question has been reasked at http://www.biostars.org/post/show/42502/how-do-i-prepare-a-pdb-for-submission-to-the-protein-data-bank/

Comment: If you don't mind I'll borrow this question to add it to the [crystallography.se](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/91841/crystallography) proposal as an example

Answer (score 3):

These two links go through the specifications required for the PDB format:

Link1: http://deposit.rcsb.org/adit/docs/pdb_atom_format.html

Link1 primarily goes through the specs. required if you say have a NMR file you would therefore require the `MODEL` statement. It also goes through other statements such as when to use `TER` and how each `ATOM` line should look etc...

Link2: http://www.wwpdb.org/documentation/format33/v3.3.html

Link2 goes through the other statements such as `HEADER`, `REMARKS` and `TITLE`